# Cryptographic Service Provider signature process

Tags: windows, cryptography, signature

---

I'm trying to create a custom CSP(cryptographic service provider) and I'm kinda stuck at signing the csp dll. In the cspdk([cspdk](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30688)) it is said, that I should use cspsign.exe to produce the signature file that can be included into the dll as a resource. But there's no such a file in cspdk or anywhere in windows.

---

So I began to google and found some posts that before 2013 people were sending their dll's to microsoft and got it signed in return. And after 2013 you are supposed to use microsoft authenticode and purchase code signing cert for it.

---

I'm in a development stage so there will be many many builds, so may be there is some simple way to get thing working.

---

So the question is how this process looks like in 2019?

**UPDATE**:
I found out that cspsign was a test utility for Windows 2000, so the cspdk is a little bit out of date. The question remains actual ..

Comment: I'd at least make sure that your dev kit is as up to date as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Those sdks are so old, with newer versions nowhere to be found, and documentation so sparse. The only reference I found on a somewhat recent process is *hidden* in here, halfway through the page: [Authenticode signing of CSPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/authenticode-signing-of-csps)

> **Note**  Starting with Windows 8, it is no longer a requirement that CSPs must be signed.

So, CSPs no longer need to be signed.